# Convert jQuery and vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this jQuery code to vanilla js

```
$(".gone").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is [NOT a free code translation service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119). Please research things like how to get elements based on *class* or how to do *click* or *hide* in vanilla javascript. If you're stuck somewhere, post it here. There are sites like http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ which help you in this regard. Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()` and `addEventListener()`

```js
var gone = document.querySelectorAll(".gone")
Array.from(gone).forEach(function(g){
  g.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="gone">Gone 1</div>
<div class="gone">Gone 2</div>
<div class="gone">Gone 3</div>
```

Comment: actually this works perfectly. It applies the listener to all classes and allows me to use this to specify which element will be affected.

Comment: @Mamun can you please explain why we are using shallow copied array(Array.from) here?

gone.forEach  - will also work directly, isn't it?

Comment: @MohdZeeshan, for some lower version of IE `forEach()` will not work. In that case you have to convert the result using `Array.from()`:)